# Mobile device viewport size and device display specs not corresponding

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm somewhat confused... I am measuring the viewport dimensions of my website so that I can optimize it for responsive web design. Now the iPhone 4 display specs are: **640x960** and the HTC desire(Bravo) has display specs of **480x800**. Now when viewing the vieport size on those devices, here are the rendered viewport dimensions as given by the following function(I am interested in the widths...):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
            $('#viewport').empty().append($(window).width(), 'x', $(window).height())
        }).resize();
```

Portrait(normal postion of phone):
    iPhone viewport **width**: **320px;**
    HTC vieport **width**: **320px;**

Landscape (When device is rotated on its side):
  iPhone viewport **width**: **480px;**
   HTC viewport **width**: **533px;**

Now this is somewhat confusing. Why doesn't it correspond with the technical display specs of the devices? Also, In [this article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/), (which btw is a good one) says that designing for smartphones' landscape and portrait dimensions, **320px min and 480px max** should suffice for all(most) smartphones, yet here, the iPhone 4 falls into that category but not the HTC...with its 533px landscape width...? So on the HTC, my site looks crap when rotating from portrait to landscape...

Any explanation/help?

Thank you